# Click event binded multiple places, how to prioritize and fire specific event

Tags: jquery

All events are binded as part of our bootstrap. For example, anchor tag with 'bootstrapclick' class is binded to click event. Now, I wanted to write additional validation onclick of anchor element, so I have written a function onclick event. But this being triggered after bootstrap click event.

Form

```
<a href='#' id='mylink' class='bootstrapclick'> Click here </a>
```

JQuery

```
var link = $('#mylink')[0]; //=> document.getElementById('mylink');
link.onclick = function(e) {
     //do additional validation
     //and prevent bootstrap click event
};
```

Suggest how do I prioritize my click event to fire first, so that I can prevent to fire bootstrap's click event.

Comment: If you want to stop the bootstrap click event completely you can use `.off()`.

Comment: change to $('#mylink'). you missed #

Comment: Hi, it is too late to use .off() because bootstrap click event is fired first and then it is firing my custom event.

Comment: @user3432047 then capture event. But, which handler do you want to prevent? Is it your own custom handler or an internal boostrap's one?

Comment: @A.Wolff I want my custom handler to be fired first where in I wanted to prevent bootstrap handler.

Comment: @user3432047 So have you tried my answer below, should be what you are expecting

Comment: So does it fix your issue???

Answer (score 0):

Try this

EDIT: This will fire on document ready - it will remove all events bound to this control, and will add onclick event handler with your logic. If bootstrap event handler is added after document ready you need to find when and remove it after it has been added `x.off();` should do that.

```
$(function(){ 
var x = $('#mylink'); 
x.off();
x.on('click', function(){

//...
});
});
```

Comment: Problem is that this event is being fired later to bootstrap event. so $(this).off() is too late?

Answer (score 0):

Capture event instead using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener): {so event would be fired before any propagating event}

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate
>   capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type
>   will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched
>   to any EventTargets beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are
>   bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener
>   designated to use capture.

```
var link = $('#mylink')[0]; //=> document.getElementById('mylink');
link.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     //do additional validation
     //and prevent bootstrap click event
     if(notValid) // or whatever you use to validate
         e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // this will prevent bootstrap click handler to be fired
}, true);
```

<strike>Now i'm not sure how bootstrap bind its own events.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Use `.off()` in jquery

```
$('#mylink').on("click" , function(event) {
       $(this).off("click");
       event.preventDefault()
       // do stuff here
 }
```